# PHP Create Session after Valid Password

Tags: php, forms, session, passwords

I want to make an PHP session after the visitor enters a valid password so I can display a few hidden links to the visitor, even on page reload.

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    $password = crypt('sumpasswurd', password_hash('rasmuslerdorf', PASSWORD_BCRYPT)); // password

    if (hash_equals($password, crypt($_POST['password'], $password))) {
        echo 'VALID!';
        // CREATE SESSION HERE
    } else {
        echo 'INVALID';
    }
}

if(isset($_SESSION)) echo 'YOU ARE LOGGED IN WITH A VALID PASSWORD!';
?>
<form method="POST" action="">
    <input type="text" name="password">
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="OK">
</form>
```

How can I make this possible? And is the encryption of my form secure?

Comment: You shouldn't need to mix up `password_hash` and `crypt`. `password_verify` should be used to confirm if a user input equals a known hash.

Comment: So.... what's the password? It's hardcoded in your file there? Is it `rasmuslerdorf`, or `sumpasswurd`? If it's hardcoded like that, why hash it at all?

Comment: It's `sumpasswurd`, I thought if someone could maybe manage to get to see the password somehow, it's a good practice to hash it in the process

Comment: If at all you hash the password and store the hash in the file; hashing is absolutely pointless if you have the literal password in your code.

Answer (score 0):

Manual session starts with `session_start()` function. Although you need to secure the session by some kind of user indetification logic. For instance, you have user's username and add it as a session variable and afterwards pass some kind of session id to verify that current session user is indeed loged in. Afterwards you have to check those variables in every pageload that is associated with user.

At: `// CREATE SESSION HERE` you might want to use something like this:

```
Session_start();
$_SESSION['username'] = $username;
// flollowed by session id logic
```